# $\sum a_n = +\infty$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ then $1$ is a singular point of the power series $\sum a_n z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum a_n z^n$ 's convergent radius be $1$, $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\sum a_n = +\infty$. Show that $1$ is a singular point of $\sum a_n z^n$.

By singular points I mean this series can't be extended to a neighborhood of $1$. I guess this can be solved by proving the Abel summation $\sum a_n r^n$ tends to $+\infty$ as $r \rightarrow 1-$. But this seems not necessarily true. Maybe more complex analysis method should be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic result related to the famous theorems of Prignsheim and Landau (when coefficients have eventually the same sign and while here this is not quite true, the hypothesis implies that the positive coefficients dominate) and one can argue as follows:

Let $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n, |z|<1, s_n =\sum_{k \le n}a_k, s_n \to \infty, g(z)=\sum s_nz^n$

Then $f(z)=(1-z)g(z)=(1-z)\sum_{k \le N} s_kz^k+(1-z)\sum_{k > N} s_kz^k=f_1(z)+f_2(z)$ for $N$ tbd.

So if we let $M>0$ we can find $N(M), s_N > M, n \ge N(M)$ so for $0<r<1$, so with the above decomposition for $N(M)$ fixed, we get $f_2(r)= (1-r)\sum_{k >N(M)}s_kr^k>(1-r)\sum_{k >N(M)}Mr^k=Mr^{N(M)+1}$

But now obviously $f_1$ is a polynomial so it is continuous on the closed unit disc and $f_1(r) \to 0, r \to 1$, so we can find $0<r_M<1, r_M^{N(M)+1} > \frac{1}{2}, |f_1(r_M)| <\frac{M}{4}$ which imples $f(r_M) >\frac{M}{4}$ by the above.

Since $M$ was arbitrary positive it follows there is a sequence $0<r_k<1, r_k \to 1$ for which $f(r_k) \to \infty$ and we are done as any extension of the function beyond the open unit disc cannot be even continuos at $1$ not to speak of being analytic